# Whitescreen render result

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

when I tried to render my project, it just get a white screen as a result. Could anyone help me? as I'm still learning on how to use blender and I don't know what is wrong with my project.

here is my blender file https://drive.google.com/file/d/18dfrGPXb2ssisoAOE2j1rkrojLsmw5-P/view?usp=sharing

I'm also using Grid Breaker from Andrey Sokolov plug-in.

Comment: Hello, it works fine for me, I can render image or animation, what does Grid Breaker do?

Comment: Hi, the project renders perfectly fine I think there is some issue with the plug-in that you used